# Вопрос о GC и контекстах

Tags: многопоточность, golang, сборщик-мусора

Что будет если....?

...Если

```
...
func fabric(i int) func() string{
    var target map[int]string//допустим,что заполненная
    return func(){return target[i]}
}
....
func testContecst(arg int){
    fmt.Println(fabric(arg)())
}
func main(){
    testContecst(1)
    testContecst(2)
    fmt.Println(fabric(3)())
    return
}
```

Так вот, когда и при выходе из какого контекста какой будет удалён map(и будет ли вообще удалён?)??

UPD: И как это работает между потоками? i.e будет ли таким же образом "выданое" число (из N) уникальным для всех потоков или для одного?

```
...
func fabric(i int) func() int{
    ii := i
    defer func(){ii++}()
    return func(){return ii}
}// во многом похоже на yield из python
....
func testContecst(arg int,id string){
    fmt.Println(id)
    fmt.Println(fabric(arg)())
}
func main(){
    go testContecst(1,"routine 1")
    go testContecst(2,"routine 2")
    fmt.Println(fabric(3)())
    fmt.Println("routine 3")
    return
}
```

Comment: Иными словами, что здесь вообще происходит?

Comment: А что вас беспокоит? В го же сборка мусора. Мап останется "живым", пока живой будет хоть одна ссылка.

Comment: Покажите пример для UPD с го-рутинами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```golang
func fabric(i int) func() string{
    // здесь вы создаёте новую мап
    var target map[int]string//допустим,что заполненная
    // здесь вы её заполняете...

    return func(){return target[i]}
    // поскольку вы возвращаете только строку из мап
    // вся мап уже становиться не нужной
    // target можно собирать, поскольку именно на неё
    // никто больше ссылаться не будет после return
}
....
// здесь мы видим только возвращённую строку
func testContecst(arg int){
    fmt.Println(fabric(arg)())
}
func main(){
    testContecst(1)
    testContecst(2)
    fmt.Println(fabric(3)())
    return
}
```